# How to get rid of white space in card

Tags: html, css

I have designed an image with some content on the card. For some reason, I am getting a space between an image and its content. How do I get rid of that space across all devices.

HTML:

```
 <div class="project-card hidden" id="modal1">
            
         <div class="overlay">
            <img src="https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/93uMH3e8dHhNEucNfioED7-TvAU=/2018/07/31/abf6d5b3-96ef-489f-b223-26a4cb70e568/img-7041.png" alt="Project1 Picture">
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <h2>Game</h2>
                <p>Lorem</p>
            </div> 
        </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.project-card{
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.2);
/*  background-color: royalblue; */  
  
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 180px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }
}

.overlay-content{
    background-color: #37393d;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

    h2{
        color: #ffde59;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        padding-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    p{
       color: #fff;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

Here is the visual representation: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zaidik/pen/oNzwvpY?editors=1100)

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [see the reason behind whitespace here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-remove-white-space-under-an-image-using-css.php)

Comment: Thank You, Really appreciate it @Pirate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the image to `display:block`:

```
    img{
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: 180px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }
```

By default images are set to `display:inline`, [as are all replaced elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements). The `div` below, however, is set to `display:block` by default. So the div wants to take up all space it can. A `display:inline` won't. So by setting it to `display:block`, you're telling the image to take up more space, and that it doesn't have to try and make the image sit inline with text.

This will be enough to eliminate the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make background of your whole card the same color as a background of your content `div`.

Just add these 2 lines in your `.project-card` class in `css` :

```
display : flex;
background-color: #37393d;
```

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: This conceals the gap. It doesn't eliminate it.

Comment: Thank You for replying. Setting display: block; seems more appropriate.